# Move constructor and vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, move, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I tried to create simple struct holding references to some values of its parent. Parent is stored within `unique_ptr`, inside a vector. It's instantiated before being moved there. After the movement, references of course are no longer valid. I found a way to reinstantiate them, but I hate the solution (it's shown below). I thought that move constructor is called on `collection.push_back(std::move(d))`, but's it's not the case for `Derived`. It might be for `unique_ptr` though, I'm not sure about that.
My question is - what should be preferred way of dealing with such situations? Is there a better solution that one I presented below? Would overriding a move constructor of `unique_ptr` help? Is this a good idea? Or, is this even a good idea to design objects in the way presented below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


// Inner object of every Base instance, is used to keep reference to
// Base's inner variables
struct Ref {
    Ref(double &x, double &y)
        : x(x)
        , y(y)
    {

    }

    std::reference_wrapper<double> x;
    std::reference_wrapper<double> y;
};


struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};


struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() { }
    // every derived class uses this vector
    std::vector<Ref> refs;

    // some meaningless pure virtual method, ignore it
    virtual void draw() = 0; 
};


struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    // Method for adding point and relating it with
    // a reference in refs vector
    void add(double x, double y) {
        points.push_back({x, y});
        refs.push_back( {points.back().x, points.back().y} );
    }

    // some meaningless pure virtual method, ignore it
    virtual void draw() override { }

    // this vector is specific to this particular derived class
    std::vector<Point> points;
};


int main() {

    // some vector for storing objects
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> collection;

    {
        auto d = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived());
        d->add(0.01, 0.02);
        d->add(1.111, 2.222);
        d->add(14.3333, 3.1414);
        collection.push_back(std::move(d));
    }

    // posible solution (I hate it)
    {
        auto d = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived());
        d->add(0.01, 0.02);
        d->add(1.111, 2.222);
        d->add(14.3333, 3.1414);
        collection.push_back(std::move(d));

        auto c = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(collection.back().get());
        for (int i = 0; i < c->points.size(); i++) {
            c->refs[i].x = c->points[i].x;
            c->refs[i].y = c->points[i].y;
        }
    }

    // Let's take 1st vector element and cast it to Derived
    {
        auto d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(collection[0].get());

        std::cout << "values from points vector:" << std::endl;
        // These work correctly after moving
        std::cout << d->points[0].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[0].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].y << std::endl;

        std::cout << "values from refs vector:" << std::endl;
        // References of course do not work anymore
        std::cout << d->refs[0].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[0].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2].y << std::endl;
    }

    // Let's take 2nd vector element and cast it to Derived
    {
        auto d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(collection[1].get());

        std::cout << "values from points vector:" << std::endl;
        // These work correctly after moving
        std::cout << d->points[0].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[0].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].y << std::endl;

        std::cout << "values from refs vector with ugly fix:" << std::endl;
        // References of course do not work anymore
        std::cout << d->refs[0].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[0].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2].y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Derived constructed
Derived constructed
values from points vector:
0.01
0.02
1.111
2.222
14.3333
3.1414
values from refs vector:
0
0.02
4.94602e-317
4.94603e-317
14.3333
3.1414
values from points vector:
0.01
0.02
1.111
2.222
14.3333
3.1414
values from refs vector with ugly fix:
0.01
0.02
1.111
2.222
14.3333
3.1414
```

Comment: Your references are getting invalidated by `points.push_back({x,y});`, not `collection.push_back(std::move(d));`.  The latter calls a move constructor of `unique_ptr`, but it's still the same `Derived` object.

Comment: Also, `Base` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: @aschepler thanks! I forgot about it - added. Wow, you're right about `points.push_back({x,y});`, no idea how I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the standard, references should not be invalidated by the move. The real problem is the `std::vector::push_back` which nvalidates everything if the capacity changes.

One solution is to use a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque) because it never invalidates reference with `push_back()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Base {
    // every derived class uses this vector
    std::vector<Point*> refs;

    // some meaningless pure virtual method, ignore it
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};


struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    // Method for adding point and relating it with
    // a reference in refs vector
    void add(double x, double y) {
        points.push_back({x, y});
        refs.push_back(&points.back());
    }

    // some meaningless pure virtual method, ignore it
    void draw() override { }

    // this vector is specific to this particular derived class
    std::deque<Point> points;
};


int main() {

    // some vector for storing objects
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> collection;

    {
        auto d = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived());
        d->add(0.01, 0.02);
        d->add(1.111, 2.222);
        d->add(14.3333, 3.1414);
        collection.push_back(std::move(d));

        // No ugly fix needed
    }

    // Let's take 1st vector element and cast it to Derived
    {
        auto d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(collection[0].get());

        std::cout << "values from points vector:" << std::endl;
        // These work correctly after moving
        std::cout << d->points[0].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[0].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[1].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->points[2].y << std::endl;

        std::cout << "values from refs vector:" << std::endl;
        // References still work
        std::cout << d->refs[0]->x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[0]->y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1]->x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[1]->y << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2]->x << std::endl;
        std::cout << d->refs[2]->y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Derived constructed
values from points vector:
0.01
0.02
1.111
2.222
14.3333
3.1414
values from refs vector:
0.01
0.02
1.111
2.222
14.3333
3.1414
```

Comment: @solusipse you can also pre allocate the vector using `vector.reserve()`. If you don't push_back past the capacity, references won't be invalidated.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot thanks, that's another thing to consider.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
  refs.push_back( {points.back().x, points.back().y} );
```

means the new entry in `refs` will refer to the members of the last entry in `points`.

But next time you do `points.push_back`, that may cause a vector reallocation which invalidates all the references already stored in `refs`.

If you really want to persist with `vector<Refs>` you will have to redesign your code to ensure that the lifetime of the objects being referred to exceeds the lifetime of the `vector<Refs>`.

The `unique_ptr` is a red herring.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'm going to use deque as Galik advised and refactor later.